# How to fix touchpad on Fujitsu UH572

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

I have read some answers about enabling touchpad on other laptops, but it does not work in my case.
I have listed devices on my laptop and found touchpad.Then I tried to enable it.

```
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 1
```

However it does not work in my case. I check my properties with

```
xinput list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"

Device Enabled (135):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (137): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (265): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (266):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (267):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (268):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (289):  1752, 5192, 1620, 4236
    Synaptics Finger (290): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (291):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (292):   221
    Synaptics Tap Durations (293):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (294):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (295):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (296):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (297):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (298): -100, -100
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (299): 1, 1, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (300):   0, 0
    Synaptics Move Speed (301): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.039809, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (302):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (303):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (304):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (305): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (306):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (307): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (308):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (309): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (310):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (311): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (312):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (313): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (314):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (315): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (316):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (317):  1
    Synaptics Gestures (318):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (319):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (320): 73, 55
    Synaptics Area (321):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (322):  3472, 0, 3900, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (323): 8, 8
    Device Product ID (254):    2, 7
    Device Node (255):  "/dev/input/event4"
```

I am not sure what to start with from here. It is enabled, but I am not sure how to set other coordinates.
I have found closed question, but it is not solved.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/246564/xinput-set-prop-does-not-work-for-touchscreen